# Challenging Algorithms Question: Proving that upper bound for computing 'silhouette' points is nlog(n)

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

Given a set of points (on the left). The silhouette set of these points is shown to the right.

[image]

In this problem, all rectangles are defined by two points, $(0, 0)$ and $(x_i, x_j)$.
Formally, for a set of points $P$, a point, $(x_1,y_1) \in P$ is in the silhouette set of $P$ if for any other point $(x_j, y_j) \in P$, $x_j\ge x_i$ and $y_j\ge y_i$.

How can we prove that any algorithm that computes the 'silhouette set' is $\Omega(n \lg n)$ under a comparison-based sorting algorithm?

We can assume no duplicate points in given set of points

---

Input: An array of pairs of integers (x, y)

Output: An array pairs of integers such that its elements give the coordinates of all the silhouette points, listed from left to right.

---

*Note that we are asked to prove that the lower bound of any comparison-based sorting approach to this problem is $Ω(n \lg n)$, not design the algorithm itself*

**Some of my Ideas**

- We know that the worst-case running time of any algorithm for sorting
  an array of integers is `Ω(n lg n)`.
- We could sort each of the sets $[x_1, x_2, x_3, \cdots]$ and $[y_1, y_2, y_3,
     \cdots]$

I am fairly stuck with any other ideas; this question trumps me greatly and I'd absolutely appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Two suggestions: (1) consider ways that you could use such an algorithm to sort a dataset (the answer will depend on what format the output is supposed to take, since the Q doesn't really cover this); (2) consider asking this on cs.stackexchange.com instead - it's probably better-suited there.

Comment: With regards to (1), I've updated the question to include the desired input and output.

Comment: Also regarding (1), I may need another tip; I don't quite understand how this algorithm could be used for sorting inherently.

Comment: Anyone have other ideas?

Comment: I'd think finding the silhouette would be more expensive than finding the convex hull.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was thinking as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a sequence of distinct numbers $A = \langle a_1, \cdots, a_n \rangle$, we can use the silhoutte algorithm to sort $A$. Associate $a_i$ with the point $(a_i, -a_i)$. Clearly for any two different points $a_j$ and $a_k$, either $a_i > a_j$ or $-a_i > -a_j$, thus all points must be in the silhouette set. Additionally, the silhouette algorithm will give these points in a sorted order from left to right and thus this corresponds exactly to $A$ in a sorted order.

Comment: Okay, so we've can reduce this algorithm to solve a sorting problem - but does that actually get us anywhere in the proof?

Comment: I've seen very something similar with convex hulls; I'll go search that up.

Comment: I can use the "silhouette algorithm" to solve the sorting problem. If the sorting problem is $\Omega(N \log N)$, then the silhouette algorithm must also $\Omega(N \log N)$ (not the other way around).